# Which behavior is undefined?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-merge

There is [undefined-behavior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior) (2 questions -  US spelling) and [undefined-behaviour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behaviour) (5 questions -  British spelling).

Please do the mod thing to sort this tag stuff out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I'm in America, I chose to use the American spelling. If you approve of this, be glad I got to this before ChrisF. If you disapprove, well, 'MURICA.

Comment: You forgot the apostrophe.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: Only the brits have the intestinal fortitude to write code in languages that have undefined behaviour.